# jquery text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

I want to make a jquery text editor and i did some googling and got a bit of a things work the basic functionality is that when a user highlights text in the textarea it will add [b] in the front and [/b] in the end of the text but what it does is if a user again clicks the same button it erases all the entered data and only places the highlighted text with the [b][/b] here is the code:

```
$('#bold').mousedown(function(e) {
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection){
        txt = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        txt = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    else return;

    txt = "[b]"+txt+"[/b]";

    $('#reply').val(txt); 
});
```

html

```
<input type="button" value="Bold" id="bold" />
<form action="" method="get">
<textarea name="reply" id="reply" cols="100" rows="30">Test</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Why re-create the wheel?

Comment: i am working on a project and when selling it off i don't want that third party stuff is included in it

Answer (score 0):

It's because the selection is being cleared after the first click. Therefore the second replacement has no text to wrap, so just adds `[b][/b]` to the textarea.

Try wrapping the lines which make the replacement in an `if` condition that checks if something was selected:

```
if (txt !== undefined && txt.length > 0) {
    txt = "[b]"+txt+"[/b]";
    $('#reply').val(txt);
}
```

Your logic appears flawed though. Imagine there is the following text in the textarea:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

If I highlight `ipsum` and click the `#bold` button, the textarea will remove all the other words and will now just say:

> [b]ipsum[/b]

There are plenty of other jQuery text editors in existence already. It will save you a lot of time to use one of these if it's a production project. If you're just trying to learn jQuery, then by all means, carry on.

Comment: txt.length does nothing instead says undefined

Comment: I've amended the condition check in my answer.